# Is there a way to more quickly find the difference between each element in a list and every other element in that list?

Tags: python, performance, data-structures, time-complexity

I'm trying to get the beat frequency between each element in a list, (get the absolute value of the difference between every element and every other element.

so if the list is

[a,b,c]

I want to generate

[a,b,c, |a-b|, |a-c|, |b-c|]

but what I'm doing right now (simply iterating through each element in the list and then iterating again) is really slow for the number of elements I'm dealing with, is there any other data structure or method I could use to make this operation faster?

The code below is what I'm doing right now. I'm somewhat new to python and haven't learned many data structures past the basics, so sorry if the solution is actually something really obvious that I haven't thought of!

I talked with my processor and he mentioned lattices, are those a purely mathematical concept or is there some implementation in code that's feasible to use, or is that even something that would be useful for my case?

Here's the code I'm running currently. It takes a list of frequencies and amplitudes, where the amplitude of the frequency at frequencies[n] is at amplitudes[n]. Once a unique beat frequency is found, it's added to the list, with an amplitude that's the mean of the amplitudes of the input frequencies, so if you have 440hz at a = 1 and 110hz at a = 2, the beat frequency would be abs(440-110) at a = ((1 + 2) / 2).

```py
def beatSet(frequencies, amplitudes, tol) :
        for index_x, x in enumerate(frequencies) :
                for index_y, y in enumerate(frequencies[index_x+1:]) :
                        beat_freq = abs(x - y)
                        if search(frequencies, beat_freq, tol) : #returns true if beat_freq isn't a duplicate, within a tolerance
                                frequencies.append(beat_freq)
                                amplitudes.append((amplitudes[index_y] + amplitudes[index_x])/2)
```

and the search function looks like this:

```py
def search(list_in, search_term, tolerance) :
        for i in list_in :
                if abs(search_term - i) <= tolerance :
                        return False
        return True
```

Generally, an input list will have somewhere around 10-50 elements, but the output has the potential to get really large, something like [440, 441] will generate an output list that's very large if there wasn't a tolerance, so the tolerance is somewhat of a limiting factor for the size of the output list. Generally, the largest output list is generated when the difference of two frequencies in the input list is just above the tolerance.

Sorry for the wall of text, hopefully I've explained everything thoroughly enough!

Comment: Couple of points: 1) I've lost track of your problem in the last paragraph. Perhaps it's a comprehension-fail on my part, but I'm not sure I see the clear question 2) Lattices might exist as a mathematical construct in Python, but certainly not as a mainstream object.

Comment: Unless you have additional knowledge about the structure of your input, there's no way to avoid checking each of the O(n^2) pairs that your O(n) input can produce.

Comment: what does the `search` function look like?

Comment: Are you aware that you are modifying `frequencies` while you are iterating over it? This might lead to a number of unexpected problems

Comment: @MaartenFabré the code for the search function iterates through the list and checks if abs(search_term - element) is <= to tolerance, and if so, it returns false. And with regards to modifying Frequencies while iterating through it, I'm aware! It's on purpose because the beat frequency calculation is meant to happen iteratively.

Comment: please add that to the original question

Comment: @chepnerso do you think the only real way I can improve speed is if I find a way to utilize how the set is ordered and possibly simplify the math or iteration that way?

Comment: [`itertools.pairwise`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes)

Comment: For the search, you can use a hash table (key/value). If key exists then you have that there already... This part will be reduced from O(n) (n/2 on average) to roughly O(1). For tolerance, it gets trickier... Not sure if you can get away without tolerance. Perhaps add both lower and upper bounds? Otherwise you have to keep that list sorted and do binary search on it.

Comment: @Ralph yeah, tolerance is sadly important, because if you have two inputs [x, lim as y -> x] and no tolerance, the set becomes infinitely large. It's possible that I'll have to keep this program as something that just takes a long time to do, haha.

Comment: If you can have lower and upper bound windows, then you don't have to add all values in the hash table, just 2, lower and upper bounds and check against those. But you have to have a fixed window values and not just a specific -X and +X values. For example if your value is 10, you can't do 10 - 5 and 10 + 5, but let it fit within the window 10 - 20 always, even if it is 10, 12, 15 or 19... I hope I am making sense, not sure if you can do that in your business logic required. Hope this helps :) Cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One problem I have with your method is that it adapts the original

You can sort the frequencies, and use `bisect` to search in the sorted list:

```
import bisect
import itertools
def beat_set(frequencies, amplitudes, tolerance):
    sorted_frequencies = sorted(zip(frequencies, amplitudes))
    results = {}
    for (
        (index_x, (freq_x, ampl_x)),
        (index_y, (freq_y, ampl_y)),
    ) in itertools.combinations(enumerate(sorted_frequencies), 2):
        beat_frequency = abs(freq_x - freq_y)
        if not search_bisect(sorted_frequencies, beat_frequency, tolerance):
            # beat_frequency already in frequencies
            continue
        beat_amplitude = (ampl_x + ampl_y) / 2
        bisect.insort_left(sorted_frequencies, (beat_frequency, beat_amplitude))
    return sorted_frequencies
(beat_set(frequencies, amplitudes, tolerance))

def search_bisect(sorted_frequencies, beat_frequency, tolerance):
    insert_index = bisect.bisect_left(sorted_frequencies, (beat_frequency,))
    if insert_index == 0:
        return abs(sorted_frequencies[0][0] - beat_frequency) > tolerance
    return all(
        abs(sorted_frequencies[insert_index - i][0] - beat_frequency)
        > tolerance
        for i in (0, 1)
)
```

The list of frequencies is updated on each found beat, but only the original frequencies are compared. In the OP's solution, the second for-loop used the updated frequency.

> ```
> frequencies = 440, 441
> amplitudes = 2, 1
> tolerance = 0.1
>
> beat_set(frequencies, amplitudes, tolerance)
> ```

```
[(1, 1.5), (440, 2), (441, 1)]
```

--

## convergence

```
def search_until_convergence(
    frequencies, amplitudes, tolerance, max_iterations=100
):
    result_new = beat_set(frequencies, amplitudes, tolerance)
    result_old = None
    for i in itertools.count():
        if i >= max_iterations:
            raise ValueError(f"No Convergence after {i} iterations")
        frequencies_new, amplitudes_new = zip(*result_new)
        if result_old == result_new:
            return {
                "frequencies": frequencies_new,
                "amplitudes": amplitudes_new,
                "iterations": i,
            }
        result_old = result_new
        result_new = beat_set(frequencies_new, amplitudes_new, tolerance)
```

Comment: Thank you! If I wanted to continue adding further orders of beat frequencies, do you think that I could utilize these ideas but call the functions until no new beat frequencies remain? Or, would that defeat the point of what you did to optimize the original code?

Comment: That is possible, I added a method that converges until the tolerance is achieved, or the maximum number of iterations is reached